# Unable to click on certain checkboxes selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of user roles, where I can select some of the roles. I'm using a switch case to select the options for the user. Problem is that I'm unable to check only certain checkboxes. It is returning NoSuchElementException. I tried debugging it and tried to click it manually, it worked. I'm unable to figure out why it is behaving differently with same set of checkboxes. Tried clicking on span, tried using id and XPath but nothing worked. I'm attaching the HTML,code and stack trace. Can somebody help me with this issue.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<span class="checklist">
<span class="">
<input id="SelectedRoleIds4" type="checkbox" value="4" name="SelectedRoleIds"/>
<a class="checkbox-select">Check</a>
<a class="checkbox-deselect">Uncheck</a>
</span>
</span>
<label for="SelectedRoleIds4" style="float: none;">SDA-Basic</label>
</div>
<div>
<span class="checklist">
<span class="">
<input id="SelectedRoleIds5" type="checkbox" value="5" name="SelectedRoleIds"/>
<a class="checkbox-select">Check</a>
<a class="checkbox-deselect">Uncheck</a>
</span>
</span>
<label for="SelectedRoleIds5" style="float: none;">SDA-Manager</label>
</div>
<div>
<span class="checklist">
<span class="">
<input id="SelectedRoleIds6" type="checkbox" value="6" name="SelectedRoleIds"/>
<a class="checkbox-select">Check</a>
<a class="checkbox-deselect">Uncheck</a>
</span>
</span>
<label for="SelectedRoleIds6" style="float: none;">SDA-Admin</label>
</div>
<div>
<span class="checklist">
<span class="">
 <input id="SelectedRoleIds7" type="checkbox" value="7" name="SelectedRoleIds"/>
 <a class="checkbox-select">Check</a>
<a class="checkbox-deselect">Uncheck</a>
</span>
</span>
<label for="SelectedRoleIds7" style="float: none;">SDD-Submit</label>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
 public static void SetRole(string[] roles)
    {
        foreach (string s in roles)
        {
           // Debug.WriteLine("role:" + s.ToLower());

            switch (s)
            {
                case "sda-basic":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds4")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "sda-manager":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds5")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "sda-admin":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds6")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "sdd-submit":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds7")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[4]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "psl-basic":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds8")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[5]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "psl-admin":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds9")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[6]/span/span/a[1]"));
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[6]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "psl-finance":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds10")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[7]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "psl-superadmin":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds11")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[8]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "psl-systems":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds12")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[9]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "sdd-basic":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds13")).Selected)
                       // Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[10]/span/span/a[1]"));
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[10]/span/span")).Click();
                    break;

                case "sdd-authorise":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds14")).Selected)
                        //Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds14")).Click();
                        // Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[11]/span/span/a[1]"));
                      //  new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds14")));
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[11]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "director":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds16")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[12]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                case "api user":
                    if (!Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRoleIds17")).Selected)
                        Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[13]/span/span/a[1]")).Click();
                    break;

                default: throw new Exception("Please select a valid Role for the User");
            }
        }

    }
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Test method SDTestAutomation.Users_Tests.Users_NewUser threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='tab-1']/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[11]/span/span/a[1]"}
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at SmartDebitTestFramework.Users.SetRole(String[] roles)
```

I couldn't select 'sdd-authorise', 'sdd-basic' and 2 more. Why does some can't be located? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See below for the best answer I can give. But it doesn't directly answer your question.  Your final question, "why can't it be located", and you give us a long xpath selector which wouldn't select anything on the HTML that you gave us, because we can't see the full tree of the HTML within context. I think my answer should put you on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that the user has some roles and permissions missing.

Answer (score 0):

You're clicking on the span. Click on the input element.  My suggestion to identify is use CSS:

`Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#SelectedRoleIds4")).Click();`

Or, if you are specifically verifying that the "a" element is performing the check click as expected, you can do the following:
`By.XPath("//input[@id="SelectedRoleIds5"]/../a[contains(@class,"-select")]")` Note that the XPath selector identifies the input field, backs up the tree one node, then selects the a element that contains the "-select" text in its class attribute value.

As an aside, I question the need to have "a" elements to do check and uncheck when the input element automatically does that when you click on it. And, whether you are working on the code-behind or during testing you can always know when the input element is selected and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Machtyn, I resolved the issue, it is because of my user roles and permissions. Thank you for your time.